# Lualatex, insert text with newline

Tags: luatex, strings

I have some trouble to understand why I can't insert newlines in lua code that is inserted in a tex document. If I do so, I've the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

MWE:

file `test.lua`:

```
tex.print("\\usepackage{tikz}\n\\usetikzlibrary{calc}")
```

file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\directlua{dofile("test.lua")}

\begin{document}%
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

compile with `lualatex test.tex`.

Answer (score 5):

The character known to Lua as `\n` is known to TeX as `^^J`. It has category code 12 (other), so when TeX encounters it outside of a definition or similar, it tries to typeset it. Since LaTeX does not allow typesetting inside the preamble, you get the error you noted.

If you read about `tex.print` in the LuaTeX manual, you may notice this:

> Each string argument is treated by TEX as a separate input line.

Therefore, you could achieve what you (probably) want by writing instead

```
tex.print("\\usepackage{tikz}","\\usetikzlibrary{calc}")
```

However, that is totally unnecessary, since having the two commands on the same line works just fine.

You might be tempted into replacing `\n` by `\r` (`^^M` in the TeX world), but that won't work either, since TeX will now see a single line with an endline character in the middle. This has the unfortunate effect of TeX ignoring the rest of the line altogether, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: Very interesting thank you. I wanted to use \n in my text for readability reason, in the code, or in the output (sometimes I output the text to a file for debugging), and it's nice to have line returns in it. The syntax with several arguments to tex.print is interesting, but if I use the escape syntax [[ ]] it's quite heavy to write that for each line. Is there a better way than using a replace function if I want to use the [[]] syntax, with newline in it, with for example a syntax close to tex.print(-2, [[ my string with newlines ]])? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm. I am quite new to LuaTeX (and Lua) myself, so I don't know if I can give good advice here. But if you set the category code of the newline character to 9 (ignore), it should cause no harm inside the argument of `tex.print`. Perhaps you could create a special `\catcodetable` with that setting, and use its number as the first argument to `tex.print`? Of course, this could get in the way if you use other catcode tricks, but if you don't, it may be the way to go. And if it doesn't work for you, maybe ask another question?